# AngularJS value as parameter in function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

AngularJS 1.3.15 
jQuery 2.1.3

'use strict'

Passing parameter to function not work.

C.change = 328;

ng-click="editMapSize( C.change )"

**in page**

> ng-click="editMapSize( C.change )"

ng-click="editMapSize( {{ C.change }} )"

**error**

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 15 of the expression
>   [editMapSize( {{C.change}} )] starting at [{C.change}} ].

.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="T in htmlTableTitle">{{ T.t }}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="R in htmlTablePrepareData">
            <td ng-repeat="C in R " 
                class="{{ C.class }}" 
                data-map-id="{{ C.change }}" 
                ng-click="editMapSize( {{C.change}} )">{{ C.value  }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**How to pass variable?**

**2. How in this case read data attribute?** 

Click on  $( this ) show $scope.

Comment: ngClick="editMapSize(C.change)">{{ ::c,value }}

Comment: ngClick="editMapSize( C.change ) in html show ngClick="editMapSize( C.change ).

With {{}} show variable. But not work "ngclick" insted of "ng-click". 
ngclick="editMapSize( 328 ) and not work.

Answer (score 1):

remove curly brackets.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="R in htmlTablePrepareData">
        <td ng-repeat="C in R " 
            class="{{ C.class }}" 
            data-map-id="{{ C.change }}" 
            ng-click="editMapSize(C.change)">{{ C.value  }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: what display in console when use this `ng-click="editMapSize( C.change )"`?

Comment: Console nothing. html -> ng-click="editMapSize( C.change )" No variable. Text.

Comment: Its simple. Now. 
$scope.editMapSize( mapId ){ console.log( mapId ); };

Answer (score 0):

When you pass variable through the angular directive, say `ng-click` or `ng-if` or anything else we need to pass the variable without angular expression i.e, avoid using curly braces. So, you can do

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="T in htmlTableTitle">{{ T.t }}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="R in htmlTablePrepareData">
            <td ng-repeat="C in R " 
                class="{{ C.class }}" 
                data-map-id="{{ C.change }}" 
                ng-click="editMapSize(C.change)">{{ C.value  }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you are using only the `change` value of `C` this is good but if you need to pass more parameters of `C` then avoid passing individual values. Instead pass the whole object like

```
ng-click="editMapSize(C)"
```

and manipulate this object in  `editMapSize` function inside controller.